# Como hacer la siguiente instrucción utilizando un ciclo Do-While en Java

Tags: java, bucles

Estoy trabajando en un pequeño programa, donde estoy teniendo problemas al momento de terminar el código con un ciclo Do-While.

**Contexto: Este programa se trata de algo más complejo, donde se desarrolla utilizando parámetros y después llamándolos en esta la 'función principal'. Pero le puse una pequeña suma de números simplemente ya que el error es en el Do while.**

El código se ve así: `

```
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        char continuar; //variable que servira para el do while
        do
        {

            System.out.print("Ingrese el numero 1: ");
            int num1 = in.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Ingrese el numero 2: ");
            int num2 = in.nextInt();
            
            System.out.println("La suma de: " + num1 + "+" + num2 + "=" + (num1+num2)  );


            System.out.print("\n-Desea procesar otra informacion (s/n)?: ");
            continuar = in.next().charAt(0);

        }
        while(continuar == 's' || continuar == 'S');
        if(continuar == 'n' || continuar == 'N'){
            System.out.println("\n-Programa terminado");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Error se esperaba 's' o 'n'");
        in.close();

    }
}`
```

**El problema es que** al finalizar el código debe preguntar si quiero continuar.

- Si es `S` o `s`, debe volver a ejecutarse
- Si es `N` o `n`, debe terminar el programa
- Si no es ninguna de las 2 condiciones anteriores, por ejemplo: (w, p, 3, 9, R), debe volver a preguntar `System.out.print("\n-Desea procesar otra informacion (s/n)?: ");`, hasta que se cumplan alguna de las 2 primeras condiciones.

He podido hacer la primera y segunda condición, pero **necesito ayuda con la tercera condición**.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: la tercera condicion debe tener su propio while que controle eso ;)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes encerrar el código que pregunta si desea continuar en otro `do..while`:

```java
do
{

    System.out.print("Ingrese el numero 1: ");
    int num1 = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Ingrese el numero 2: ");
    int num2 = in.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("La suma de: " + num1 + "+" + num2 + "=" + (num1+num2)  );


    do {
        System.out.print("\n-Desea procesar otra informacion (s/n)?: ");
        continuar = in.next().charAt(0);
    } while (continuar != 's' && continuar != 'S' && continuar != 'n' && continuar != 'N')
}
while(continuar == 's' || continuar == 'S');
```